# How to see .w trigger is working for my query?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Just for the knowledge I just want to see how WRITE triggers execute for the query below. Is it possible to see them?.

```
    FOR EACH Customer EXCLUSIVE-LOCK WHERE NAME = "Go Fishing Ltd":
      ASSIGN  Customer.Balance = 600.
    END.
```

Comment: Do you mean that you expect that a WRITE trigger is executing and wish to confirm that?

Comment: @TomBascom Yes.. Correct!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the `log-manager` show the write trigger being executed on the sports2020 database:

```
def var clog as char no-undo.
def var lclog as longchar no-undo.

assign
    clog = guid + '.log'.
    log-manager:logfile-name = clog
    log-manager:log-entry-types = '4gltrace:5,4glmessages'
    .

for each Customer exclusive-lock where name = 'Go Fishing Ltd':
    Customer.Balance = Customer.Balance + 1. // write trigger only fires when record changes
end.

log-manager:close-log().
copy-lob from file clog to lclog.
message string( lclog ).
```

https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=62978a833fb02369b25479f0

Relevant snippet from the output:

```
4GLTRACE       Return from Main Block "Customer Customer" [sports2020trgs/wrcust.p]
```

Comment: When I use log-manager:close-log() which means created log file will be deleted?

Comment: Is it possible to delete them after it got closed ??

Comment: google site:docs.progress.com close-log

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
-clientlog path/to/log.log -logginglevel 4 -logentrytypes 4GLTrace
```

to your startup command.

This will create a log of all of the calls that your code makes.

For more information: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/P9893

You can also use the LOG-MANAGER system handle within your code to dynamically control the logging at runtime:

https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-troubleshoot-applications/page/LOG-MANAGER-system-handle-attributes-and-methods.html

but for simple purposes like this it is easier to just add the startup parameters.

Comment: I can see like this.. I dont see the WRITE trigger executing

[22/06/01@20:40:44.607+2300] P-013044 T-012872 3 4GL 4GLTRACE   Return from Main Block [C:\OpenEdge\WRK\p63080_Untitled1.ped]

Comment: If there is a write trigger executing you should see a [22/06/01@17:43:01.738+0200] P-023828 T-014176 3 4GL 4GLTRACE       Return from Main Block "<table>" [<trigger.p>]

Comment: are you sure the value in the record changes, write trigger only fires if something changed