# Progress 4GL - Is there any way to find out .p 's calling triggers(.t)?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is there any other way to find out what all the triggers (.t) files getting called while running. r ?. I am struggling to find out correct trigger files used for particular programs.

Please help me on this

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see what a black box is doing is to use [-clientlogging](https://docs.progress.com/en-US/bundle/openedge-startup-and-parameter-reference-117/page/Client-Logging-clientlog.html) with [-logentrytype](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-startup-and-parameter-reference-117/page/Log-Entry-Types-logentrytypes.html) 4GLTrace.

> Turns on logging for the execution of internal procedures, user-defined functions, persistent user-interface triggers, and named events (generated by the RUN, FUNCTION, PUBLISH, and SUBSCRIBE statements, respectively). It also logs the instantiation and use of classes, including execution of constructors (invoked by the NEW phrase and also by the SUPER and THIS-OBJECT statements), the execution of methods defined within classes (including those invoked using the SUPER system reference), the execution of property accessor methods (invoked by accessing a property of a class), and the execution of destructors (invoked by executing the DELETE OBJECT statement).

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the client startup parameters look for Stefan's answer with LOG-MANAGER.

[How to see .w trigger is working for my query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463842/how-to-see-w-trigger-is-working-for-my-query)

Alternatively, you can write the code yourself.  A write trigger fires at end of record scope or at the end of a transaction, whichever comes first. This can lead to tricky situations. My proposal does not display the trigger program file name, only the table name.

Try:

```
/*test.p*/
for each _file no-lock where _tbl-type = "T":
   run write.p persistent _file-name.
end.

find first customer.
update name.
```

It runs write.p for each table in your database. If you have multiple databases connected just repeat the for each for each connected database.

```
on write of {1} do:
   def var i as int.
   i = 1.
   do while program-name(i) <> ? with down col 10 overlay row 4:
      display "{1}" program-name(i) format "x(35)".
      i = i + 1.
   end.
end.
```

The results do not give you the trigger program file name, but it provides the table name.

```
┌────────────────────┐
│Name                │
│────────────────────│
│Etienne ┌────────────────────────────────────────────┐
└────────│Customer WRITE-TRIGGER write.p              │
         │Customer /home/ebegin/p71715_test.ped       │
         │Customer adecomm/_runcode.p                 │
         │Customer ExecuteRun adeedit/_proedit.p      │
         │Customer RunFile adeedit/_proedit.p         │
         │Customer USER-INTERFACE-TRIGGER adeedit/_pro│
         │Customer adeedit/_proedit.p                 │
         │Customer _edit.p                            │
```

Another approach is to use the PROFILER system handle. The profiler provides processing time and call-tree information.

There is profiler integration in PDSOE if you use that software.